# Getting Table Data and Storing it using Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Suppose I have a table like this

```
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>THK-ASA-AKK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>KAL-ASA-AKK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>MAK-ASA-AAKS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>ABC-ASA-AKK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>BSA-ASA-AKK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>KAL-ASA-AKK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to find the contents for the Code header for Ernst- which are two in number. How can I achieve that using Protractor.

I am currently trying to locate the element using the following piece of code

```
element.all(by.cssContainingText('td','Ernst')).elment(by.css('td:nth-child(3)')).getText().then(function(code){
console.log(code)});
```

However, the script runs without any issue but the text is not printed. How can this be done.

Comment: I have no idea on protractor. but suggest trying following code `element.all(by.cssContainingText('tr','Ernst')).elment(by.css('td:nth-child(3)')).getText().then(function(code){
console.log(code)});`. first find tr which contains text `Ernst`, then find 3rd child in that row.

Comment: I've already tried this one. It's not working

Comment: I suggest breaking down the problem. first check whether `element.all(by.cssContainingText('tr','Ernst'))` matching elements. I doubt that. check also if it is inside a frame.

Comment: No. Not inside an iframe.

Comment: element.all(by.cssContainingText('tr','Ernst')) is returnig elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Filter to find the tr with the text

So we need to go through each table row and use the filter function. The [filter](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function will allow us to return an [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) object which is a collection of rows where the condition is met. The condition we are trying to meet is where a specific table data text includes the text 'Ernst'.

So from the `tr`, we will need to get the collection of `tds` that are within that table row. We will return the promised boolean from the text of the first column that contains the text 'Ernst'. When this is true, we will add this to the [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) object.

```
let ernstTrs = element.all(by.tagName('tr')).filter(tr => {
  tds = tr.all(by.tagName('td'));
  return tds.get(0).getText().then(text => {
    return text.includes('Ernst');
  });
});
```

### Look up the code table data from the tr

After we have the `ernstTrs`, we can get the first element to get an [ElementFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) object. We will do the same search to get a collection of `td`'s. Get the 3rd column at index 2 and we will get the text from it and print it out to console.

```
let ernstTr = ernstTrs.get(0); // get an ElementFinder from the ElementArrayFinder

let ernstTds = ernstTr.all(by.tagName('td'));
let ernstTdCode = ernstTds.get(2);

// let's output the ernst code in column 2:
ernstTdCode.getText().then(text => {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Happy Protractor-ing!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went the same approach using the `filter` method.